# SQL Server: Copy Live Data from View to Table

Tags: sql-server, view, triggers

right now I have a challenge what I'm not sure about how to solve in the best manner. I searched the internet but did not find a suitable solution ...

I want to copy data from a view on a linked server (read only; view has severals sub views and tables) to a table which is located on my database. This View contains live data, basically showing the last 100 occuring events. However, what I need is the whole history of the data shown by the view. As I have just reading permission on that specific view and the admin of the linked server is not able (or willing) to give further rights or change the view, I was wondering what the best way is to copy the view data and basically building up the whole history on my database.

I was thinking about a stored procedure and run it on a schedule, but as the last 100 events can change very quickly, this does not seem like an appropriate approach. Another option would be to build a trigger, which takes new rows an copies them to my table. However, I'm not sure if this would be possible.

I appreciate any hints, tips or impulses.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: Basically if I can achieve my goal by means of a view trigger and if so, how such a trigger would look like. I did some unlucky trying with INSTEAD OF trigger and did not make it work.

Comment: If you cannot change the source database, then you cannot put any triggers there either.  There's no way to do this with triggers (or anything else) on the target database.  The best you can do is to snapshot the source view on some short timing cycle and use Type 2 ETL to remove the duplicates.

Comment: So put the question you are asking in the question; it is a **question** after all. At the moment we have no clear problem statement, and no clear answerable problem. [so] isn't a discussion forum, so asking for hints and tips is off topic.

Comment: _last 100 events_ That is a significant statement but it is not clear if that was intentional or not. And you mention "whole history" but that conflicts with the idea of "live data". Your options are very limited if you have only read-access to this view. TBH this is a discussion you should be having with the groups that are responsible for your work and  these two systems. At this point it seems taking a periodic snapshot is one path, but it is not clear how you intend to use this information. That fact might be a significant factor in your design.